# Redux state returns Proxy

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am having a problem where redux `@connect` is returning `Proxy` for one of my props but only when my component is being re-rendered after it opens (due to a tab change). This is what `this.props` returns after the component re-renders (all other connected state variable are correct). But I get the following error that `medias.videos` is `undefined` - `MediaModal.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined(…)`.

[image: this.props]

I have a component called `MediaModal.js`:

```
...
@connect(
  state => ({ isVisible: state.media.isVisible, activeKey: state.media.activeKey, medias: state.media.medias }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({ open, close }, dispatch))

export default class MediaModal extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  static propTypes = {
    isVisible: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    activeKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    open: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    close: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    medias: PropTypes.shape({
      playlists: PropTypes.array,
      videos: PropTypes.array
    }).isRequired
  }

render () {
    const styles = require('./MediaModal.scss')
    const { isVisible, open, close, activeKey, medias } = this.props
    console.log(this.props)
    ...
    let allMedias = medias.playlists.concat(medias.videos)// <---------------- this line throws the following error MediaModal.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined(…)
    }
}
```

Its connected to a redux model called `media.js`:

```
const OPEN_MODAL = 'lively/media/OPEN_MODAL'

...
const initialState = {
  isVisible: false,
  activeKey: 1,
  medias: {
    playlists: [],
    videos: []
  }
}

export default function reducer (state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_MODAL:
      return {
        isVisible: true,
        activeKey: action.activeKey,
        medias: action.medias
      }
    ...
}

export function open (activeKey, medias) {
  return {
    type: OPEN_MODAL,
    activeKey,
    medias
  }
}
```

The code that calls `open`:

```
import { open as _openMediaModal } from 'redux/modules/media'

@connect(
  state => ({
  }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    openMediaModal: _openMediaModal
  }, dispatch)
)

export default class Discover extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        openMediaModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        if (props.id === "all") {
            this.state = { discover: Data.getAll(), key: props.id }
        } else {
            this.state = { discover: Data.getDiscoverById(props.id), key: props.id }
        }
        this.options = Data.getOptions()
    }

    ...

    render() {
        const {
            openMediaModal
        } = this.props
        const packages = this.state.discover.packages
     ...
{ Object.keys(packages).map((key) => {
                            <a href="#medias" className={styles.video}  onClick={() => openMediaModal(1, packages[key].medias)} style={ { backgroundImage: `url(${packages[key].videoThumbnail})` } }  >
                                <Glyphicon glyph="play-circle" className={styles.playIcon} />
                            </a>
     ...
```

Comment: Please add the code that calls `open`.

Comment: Hi @JimBolla I added the code that calls open. Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: So, **what is the problem** you are having?

Comment: The state variable `medias` has value `Proxy` when it should have a value of type `Object` that looks like `{playlists: [...], videos: [...]}`. It does have this value the first time render is called but not the second time - I imagine this is due to a scope issue and maybe I should take a copy of the object and store it into state...?

Comment: Does it matter? Probably you can just use the proxy like you'd use the object, that's what proxies are made for after all. So is there anything that does not work with the proxy?

Comment: @Bergi Yes because I get an error when I use the Proxy on this line: `let allMedias = medias.playlists.concat(medias.videos)` 

And the error is: `MediaModal.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined(…)`